# Build a custom object call

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this (it can be infinite) :

```
list: [
 {
   list: [
     {
       list: [
         {...}
       ]
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   list: [
     {...}
   ]
 },
 {
   list: [
     {...}
   ]
 }
];
```

And an array that indicates me where i should be hitting in this object ; for exemple if I want to go in the 2nd list of the 3rd list if will have this :

```
target = [3, 2];
```

I can to create a custom call to get the correct object in 'list' using my 'target' array.

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT :**

I just did :

```
var array = list;

for (var i = 0; i < target.length; i++) {
  array = array[target[i]].list;
}
```

And it worked.

Thanks

Comment: What *specific* problem are you facing?

Comment: I am triing to push in the list a new item depending on the deepness of it.

I want to do:
customTarget.push(newItem);

With customTarget being built using a loop :

list[3].list[2].list.push(newItem);

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for something like this:

```
var obj = {
  list:[
    {
    list: [
        {
        list: []
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    list: [
        {
        list: []
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    list: [
        {
        list: []
        },
      {
        list: []
        },
      {
        list: []
        },
      {
        list: [
            {
            list: [],
            a: 5
          }
        ]
        }
    ]
  }
  ]
};


function getListObject(theList, indexes) {
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++) {
    theList = (theList && theList.list) ? theList.list[indexes[i]] : null;
  }
  return theList;
}

alert(getListObject(obj, [2, 3, 0]).a);
```

You can do it with a reduce, if you want, but I'll keep it simple with a for loop.

Please note that I'm passing in an OBJECT with a list property, and I'm getting an object with a list property back.
Building a function which gets an array and gives back an object is a simple edit, but I felt it was not in the intent.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As the object can be deeply nested, you could also try recursion as below:

```
function getList(list, target){                          
  var index = target[0] - 1;        

  if (target.length === 1) return list[index];            

  return getList(list[index].list, target.slice(1));
}

// invoke : var sublist = getList(obj.list, [3, 1]);
//  sublist.push({});
```